# How to make json Object in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to send the following JSON object to one of the API. Can anyone please tell me how to convert this into JSON object in JAVA by using org.json lib.

{
"hostHeaderInfo": 
{"sourceCode": "xxx",
"requestId": "xxx",
"requestToken": "xxx",
"requestType": "xxx",
"affiliateCode": "xx",
"sourceChannelId": "xxx"
},

"number":"xxxx",
"first":"xx",
"second":"xx"
}

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

In Java we have jackson bind JSON API to convert Java to JSON and JSON to Java.

**JSON String to Java:**

JSON:

```
String data = "{ "hostHeaderInfo": {"sourceCode": "xxx", "requestId": "xxx", "requestToken": "xxx", "requestType": "xxx", "affiliateCode": "xx", "sourceChannelId": "xxx" }, "number":"xxxx", "first":"xx", "second":"xx" }"; 

JavaObject obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, JavaObject.class);
```

**Java Object to JSON:**

```
JavaObject obj = ;  //Java class object reference here
String data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Note: Here `JavaObject` can be any class which will fields as required by JSON